# Восстановление слова

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер - возможно ли с данного кода восстановить начальный string?

```
public static byte[] RustProtect = new byte[]
        {
            240,
            76,
            195,
            15,
            241,
            188,
            91,
            219,
            149,
            168,
            22,
            28,
            150,
            190,
            125,
            106
        };

string text2 = @string.Remove(0, Core.ChatCommandKey.Length).ToLower();
byte[] md = Helper.GetMD5(text2);
if (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(md) == Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RustProtect ))
```

Comment: А почему `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` и `==`, а не `SequenceEquals`? И да, MD5 не является стойким криптографическим хешем.

Comment: Разве что полным перебором всех строк.